# Convergence of series $\sum \sin^nx$ and $\sum \cos x\sin^nx$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> (a) Find all $x$ in $[0,2 \pi]$ for the which series $\sum \sin^nx$ is convergent.
>
> (b) Find all $x$ in $[0,2 \pi]$ for the which series $\sum \cos x\cdot\sin^nx$ is convergent.

For (a)
clearly, $\sum \sin^nx$ is geometric series

$\therefore$ for convergence $|\sin x|< 1 $

or $|\sin x| != 1$

or $ x \in [0,2 \pi] - {\pi/2, 3 \pi/2}$

Is this argument correct?
If so then exact answer is valid for part (b) as well?

EDIT/UPDATE: as Paul pointed out for (b) the answer should be $ x \in [0,2 \pi]$ and NOT $ x \in [0,2 \pi] - {\pi/2, 3 \pi/2}$ since for $x = \pi/2 or 3 \pi/2$, the series in (b) is simply a constant series of 0 and hence convergent.

Comment: Assuming $n \rightarrow \infty$ , that is true,similarly you can take the case when $\sin(x) \neq -1$.Ok you have taken it

Comment: @MyGlasses ,a factor of n will be multiplied I guess?,I think for (b) we are simply multiplying $\cos(x)$ to the first series and since $|cos(x)| \leq 1$ it has no severe effect on divergence,and the condition remains the same as the previous one.

Comment: Have another look at (b) for the special cases

Comment: @BAYMAX, the condition isn't exactly the same.  The second series converges where the first does not.

Comment: Why so,why not the series converges except specific two values in the interval specified?@Paul

Comment: Because for the two points for which a does not converge the terms in b are all zero.

Comment: Yup,nice one @Paul